# Postgresql query slow: compare 2 text columns from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables a and b. Table a has about 600,000 rows and 6 text columns and Table b has about 30,000 rows and 6 text columns. I am trying to doing this

```
create table c as
select *
from a, b
where a.file_name between b.starting_file_name and b.ending_file_name;
```

I have file_name indexed on a and both starting_file_name and ending_file_name indexed separately on b. Surprising this takes more than 1 hour or so on my HP Proliant ML350p Server (64GB memory)

Here are some additional configurations on the Postgres:

```
shared_buffers = 16GB
work_mem = 1GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 32GB
```

Explain:

```
Nested Loop (cost=0.00..261971798.23 rows=2685032391 width=250)" " 
Join Filter: (a.file_name >= b.starting_file_name)" " 
-> Seq Scan on a (cost=0.00..21144.88 rows=618988 width=162)" " 
-> Index Scan using b_ending_file_name_idx on b (cost=0.00..228.00 rows=13013 width=88)" " 
     Index Cond: (a.file_name<= b.end_file_name)"
```

also tried

```
create table c as
select *
from a, b
where a.file_name >=b.starting_file_name
and a.file_name<= b.ending_file_name;
```

Here is the explain:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..261971798.23 rows=2685032391 width=250)"
"  Join Filter: (a.file_name>= b.starting_file_name)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..21144.88 rows=618988 width=162)"
"  ->  Index Scan using b_ending_file_name_idx on b  (cost=0.00..228.00 rows=13013 width=88)"
"        Index Cond: (a.file_name<= b.end_file_name)"
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the resulting query plan is? And the cardinality / number of matching tuples? And the size of the text columns?

Comment: Each text column is less than 100 characters. I am not sure about matching tuples. Thank you

Comment: looks like missing statistics. [BTW: please add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results to your question; not to the comments] BTW2: `between` on a text column is suspect. to say the least...

Comment: do the filenames actually stem from the same (limited) domain?

Comment: Example: a.file_name: 'abc005.txt', b.starting_file_name: 'abc001.txt' and b.ending_file_name: 'abc100.txt'. Does that answer your question?

Comment: but their length is 200 chars ?

Comment: The query as posted does not work (BETWEEN is *not a function*). Did you mean: `JOIN b ON a.file_name BETWEEN b.starting_file_name AND b.ending_file_name` PLEASE POST THE REAL CODE.

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the wrong code. The syntax for between is "between X and Y" and it is not "between(X,Y)". I've corrected the code in the post. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I used text for the file_name, starting_file_name and ending_file_name. I could've used character(50) for them but I read from Postgres tutorial that there was not significant performance boost so I did not bother to change.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with a composite index on `(b.starting_file_name, b.ending_file_name)`.

---

Also, if the strings are generally unique within the first relatively short number of characters, you could create an expression index on a substring, then do a recheck for the full length, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX b_filename_prefixes ON b ( 
  left(starting_file_name, 20),
  right(ending_file_name, 20)
);
```

and then

```
select *
from a, b
where 
  left(a.file_name, 20) between left(b.starting_file_name, 20) and left(b.ending_file_name, 20)
  and a.file_name between b.starting_file_name and b.ending_file_name;
```

I've tested this on some trivial sample data to confirm the planner will identify the index as a candidate, and it does.